# Increment each pixel in BitmapData

Tags: flash, colors, bitmap

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. I want to create a kind of "age map" of an image. This means that every frame

- Each pixel's value is incremented by 1.
- Modified pixels are set to 0.

Is there a way to do this efficiently without looping through all pixels and calling `getPixel`/`setPixel`?

For resetting the modified pixels I'm thinking of using `bitmapData.draw()`, with a combination of blendModes/colorTransform; e.g. draw the shape over the age map using a 0 colorTransform, preserving shape but making the shape black, i.e. `0x000000`.

However, incrementing each pixel by 1 is maybe more tricky. I could create an image with all `0x000001` values, and use `.draw()` to add it each frame, but using `BlendMode.ADD` clips each channel at `0xFF`, allowing only 255 different age values.

Any suggestions for going about this efficiently? Can I maybe apply a `ColorTransform` or `ColorMatrixFilter` to the whole image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom PixelBender filter, this will be much, much quicker than iterating over pixels:

This may be of some use if you've never used before:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/pixel-bender-custom-filters/

I'm a bit rusty with PB myself, sorry I can't offer more specific advice, but know this is possible and the GPU-support means it'll be quick enough to be useable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thing is I'm using Haxe; so PixelBender support is a bit questionable. I ended up using only the blue channel, applying a ColorTransform that has `blueOffset = 1` each frame. That limits me to 255 values though.